# Element dimensions are updating in the DOM but the changes aren't displaying onresize

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, svg

I'm trying to resize a `svg` element to fit as large as possible in the browser while maintaining a 100x50 scale. When I inspect the changes made to the DOM, everything checks out fine, but the updated dimensions don't seem to render. How do I fix this problem?

http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/SE6d3/show/

```
var svg = document.getElementById("svg");
resize.call(svg);

window.onresize = function() {
    resize.call(svg);
}

function resize() {    
    this.setAttribute("width", scale(100));
    this.setAttribute("height", scale(50));

    function scale(value) {
        return Math.min(window.innerWidth / 100, window.innerHeight / 50) * value;
    }
}
```

---

**Edit:** [sq2's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11623246/522877), which changes the code from

```
    this.setAttribute("width", scale(100));
    this.setAttribute("height", scale(50));
```

to

```
    this.style.width = scale(100);
    this.style.height = scale(50);
```

provides a fix, but is still broken in Firefox.

Comment: I think I misunderstood something. I open the demo in latest Firefox, try to resize the browser's window and the black box is always resized the way that its width and height maintain the 2:1 ratio. What should happen instead?

Comment: @duri - The version above doesn't work in Chrome. Using `this.style[attribute]` fixes Chrome, but doesn't work in Firefox. See: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/SE6d3/16/show

Comment: I might be missing something, but why don't you just resize through CSS? http://jsfiddle.net/RqUY3/

Comment: @Duopixel - that doesn't produce a 100x50 scale.

Comment: The "SVG" way of doing this would be setting the viewBox attribute, but I'm not sure you want your content centered http://jsfiddle.net/rpzPX/

Comment: The `SVG` element is not the only element on my page. I cannot use something that takes up the entire screen.

Comment: Use Math.min instead of 'minimum'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
Also this http://jsfiddle.net/SE6d3/70/ is working everywhere and resize is working in Chrome and Firefox with proportions 100 to 50

***Edit: Rather than setting the width/height attributes, set the width/height CSS style.***

---

You have no problems at attr/style level: try this http://jsfiddle.net/SE6d3/27/
All working normal if firefox and chrome.

I think your problem on level of getting width/height from window.
Try this methods:

```
getClientHeight = function(){
    return document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat' ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : document.body.clientHeight;
};

getClientWidth = function(){
  return document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat' ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : document.body.clientWidth
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why that is intermittently working, very strange and curious to see if there is a better answer.

But... replacing:

```
this.setAttribute("width", scale(100));
this.setAttribute("height", scale(50));
```

with:

```
this.style.width = scale(100);
this.style.height = scale(50);
```

renders it correctly on screen in Chrome, however I am doubtful that setting style of SVGs is the correct approach.

Comment: Interesting. I'm curious why setting the attribute doesn't work, but this works fine as well. Thank you.

Comment: Upon further review, firefox is still broken unfortunately.