# How do I queue an attribute change if another animation is in progress, using SVG.js?

Tags: javascript, svg.js

I am using SVG.js, I have 2 widgets on the page,

widget1 has an animation that changes the radius of a circle over a second.

```
topElement.animate({ duration: "1s" }).radius(newRadius);
```

Widget2 has a callback which changes one of its circles' opacity from 0.0 to 1.0 on mouseover.

```
overrideElement.attr("opacity", "1.0");
```

However, if I mouseover widget2 while the animation is happening on widget1 the opacity change doesn't happen and it is vital.

Can I queue the opacity change if another animation is in progress?

Comment: Actually I don't think the other animation has anything to do with it, the opacity change simply doesn't happen sometimes even though the value of opacity has changed if I print it out in the console.

Comment: If I use     svgDocument.getElementById(widgetOverrideId).setAttribute("opacity", "1.0");      the change still doesn't happen sometimes.

Comment: Please create a real code example on jsfiddle or codepen and show your issue

Comment: I found a fix on [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622992/element-dimensions-are-updating-in-the-dom-but-the-changes-arent-displaying-onr/11692456] by using CSS to change the opacity rather than setAttribute